# $T_S = \{f^{-1}(A), A\subseteq X \mbox{ open} \}$, and $f\circ g$ continuous $\iff $ $g$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, T_x)$ be a topological space, $S$ a set and $f:S\to X$ a function.

1) Show that $T_S = \{f^{-1}(A), A\subseteq X \mbox{ open} \}$ is a topology in S.

2) Show that $T_S$ is the greater one that turns $f$ continuous.

3) If $S$ is given the topology $T_{S}$, show that $g:Z\to S$ is continuous $\iff$ $f\circ g:Z\to X$ is continuous.

My attempt to solve each one:

1) $T_S$ is the set of inverse functions of $f$ applied to an open $A$ of $X$. I need to prove that $\emptyset$ and $S$ are in it. We know that $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, and that $S\subset f^{-1}(S)$ because... why?. Now I need to argue that the union of $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are opens in $X$ is also in $T_S$. Well, $A\cup B$ is open in $S$, therefore $f^{-1}(A\cup B)$ is in $T_S$, but $f^{-1}(A\cup B) = f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$, so the union is still in $S$. I just need to translate this argument to an arbitrary union. The finite intersection follows the same principle, right? So I've shown this is a topology.

2)

Here I need to argue something about finer topologies, right? I don't know if I translated this right from portuguese to english, but it should be understood as 'least finer'. By 'least finer' I must understand that it's the biggest one that can make $f$ continuous. How should I prove such thing?

3)

A continuous function $f$ can be defined as a function such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open when $U$ is open. So, if $f\circ g$ is continuous, it means that $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(U)$ is open when $U$ is open. Can I say here that $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ must be continuous in order for $U$ to be mapped to another open set? Now, how about the other side? Why $g$ being continuous should implicate that $f\circ g$ is? No suppositions about the continuity of $f$ are needed?

Answer (score 1):

1. To show $S \in T_S$, you need to show $S=f^{-1}(A)$ for some $A \subseteq X$ which is open. What (open) subset of $X$ has inverse image all of $S$? You are correct about the unions and intersections. They "play nicely" with inverse images, so it is simple to "upgrade" your argument about finite unions to arbitrary unions: if $U_i$ is open in $X$ for all $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{i \in I}U_i$ is as well, and $f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \right) = \bigcup_{i \in I} f^{-1}(U_i)$.
2. I think the word you are looking for is "coarsest." Actually this will be the smallest topology that makes $f$ continuous. ($f$ will always be continuous if $S$ is given the discrete topology, which is the finest and largest topology on $S$.) What you need to show is that if $f$ is continuous with respect to another topology $T$ on $S$, then $T_S \subseteq T$. Take a set $U \in T_S$. Then it is of the form $f^{-1}(A)$ for some $A \subseteq X$ open. Then why must $f^{-1}(A) \in T$?
3. What are the assumptions on $f$ here? This statement is not true in general. For instance, if $Z=\mathbb{R}$, $S=\mathbb{R}$, $X=\mathbb{R}$, $g=1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (the indicator function of the rationals), and $f=0$, then $f \circ g=0$ is continuous but $g$ is not.

Comment: What I understood the OP post is that he did want $S$ is to be given the quotient topology induced by $f$.

Comment: @user284331 That may be, in which case your answer suffices for that part of the questions. It wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @user284331 the topology on $S$ is called the initial topology on $S$ with respect to $f$. It's dual to the quotient topology, where we have a topology on the domain of $f$ and induce one on the codomain. Here we have a topoloy on $X$ and "pull it back" to $S$ using $f$. The subspace topology is an example of this where $f$ would be the canonical embedding function.

Comment: You are right, I have messed up the name of the topology.

Answer (score 0):

I solve 3) here. Assuming that $g:Z\rightarrow S$ is continuous, given open set $G$ of $X$, then $f^{-1}(G)$ is open in $S$. By the continuity of $g$, one has $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(G))$ is open in $Z$. Note that $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(G))=(f\circ g)^{-1}(G)$, so the continuity of $f\circ g$ follows.

Now assume that $f\circ g$ is continuous. Given open set $H$ of $S$, then $H=f^{-1}(A)$ for some open set $A$ of $X$. By the continuity of $f\circ g$, one has $(f\circ g)^{-1}(A)=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))=g^{-1}(H)$ is open in $Z$, so the continuity of $g$ follows.

Comment: why $f^{-1}(F)$ is open? There's no assumption about $f$

Comment: The topology on $S$ is defined exactly for those preimages of $f$ of open sets $A$ of $X$.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, so $f$ is continuous in $S$, right?

Comment: Definitely, pure definition.